# swapping /boot partiton

Tags: boot, grub2, fstab

About 6 months ago I installed a newly acquired laptop with kubuntu .
I opted for a separate /boot (and accepted the default) now, during the upgrade to the next kubuntu version it runs out of space in /boot (it's cleaned up, it's just too small)

boot=sda5
root=sda7

So I thought, OK I'll drop having a separate /boot and just use /boot as a directory on the root partition . So:

1. created /newboot (on root filesystem)
2. cp -a /boot/* /newboot (& rmdir /newboot/lost+found)
3. umount /boot
4. mv /boot /oldboot, mv /newboot /boot
5. edit /etc/fstab   (mount old /dev/sd5 as /oldboot)
6. systemctl daemon-reload
7. update-initramfs -u

Now I diffed /boot/grub/grub.cfg with /oldboot/grub/grub.cfg

And they were identical...huum I thought , well many of the settings there are ["suggestions"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744041/how-is-grub2-able-to-hardcode-root) grub actually goes looking for files ...problem is, there is for example a "good" grub.cfg on both  sda5 (msdos5) and sda7 (msdos7) it could find either.
So I hand edited all references to msdos5 to msdos7 in grub.cfg and reran
update-initramfs -u, rebooted and it all came up fine......

But I had this doubt ... did it use "/boot" or is it still using "/oldboot"  ... so on oldboot there were 2 kernels (and initrd)  say vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic and vmlinuz-6.2.0-35-generic I renamed one to NOT-vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic and rebooted. ... it failed , I selected the "35" version and it came up fine....**so it's still reading /oldboot.**

**So what step am I missing** . Do I need to hand edit the UUID? Seems very failure prone...feels like there's some simple "regen the grub.cfg" step I'm missing ...reinstall grub?

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see why nobody jumped in to give a quick answer ...it's way more complicated.

So the trivial bit was

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

But that's far from the whole story. First more information was needed:

1. The system uses (old style) BIOS boot
2. The laptop has a pre-existing "Doze" installation and uses it's initial bootloader + BCD

So first al the above steps are needed. Then the  above **grub-mkconfig**, this makes changes:

```
root@ThinkPad:/boot/grub# diff grub.cfg.5nov23 grub.cfg
173c173
<   set root='hd0,msdos5'
---
>   set root='hd0,msdos7'
175c175
<     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  7094b250-3ccf-436e-af52-6c0d828cc15c
---
>     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  e8128f48-1ef6-44e6-b95c-1595c6ddf05c
177c177
<     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7094b250-3ccf-436e-af52-6c0d828cc15c
---
>     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e8128f48-1ef6-44e6-b95c-1595c6ddf05c
179,180c179,180
<   linux   /vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic root=UUID=e8128f48-1ef6-44e6-b95c-1595c6ddf05c ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
<   initrd  /initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
---
>   linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic root=UUID=e8128f48-1ef6-44e6-b95c-1595c6ddf05c ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
>   initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
191c191
...
```

In essence: changing SDA5 to SDA7, changing paths from /grub to /boot/grub and the UUIDs.

But the final step needed (in my case) is **grub-install /dev/sda7**

The reasons are slightly complex, I'll cover 2 cases 1st mine and 2nd the more common one of the initial bootloader being grub (with or without a Doze partition)

Here was my case:

```
root@ThinkPad:/boot/grub# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-35-generic
Found memtest86+x64 image: /boot/memtest86+x64.bin
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
done

root@ThinkPad:/boot/grub# grub-install /dev/sda7
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Filesystem `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.


root@ThinkPad:/boot/grub# grub-install --force /dev/sda7
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Filesystem `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

In my case the laptop boots using the Doze bootloader, it then uses BCD (a boot utility) to allow selection of boot partition ... it used to allow 1 (Doze) or 5 (Kubuntu) , I added 7 (SDA7=root)

So this means the grub bootloader needs to be on /dev/sda7 and as the warning suggests it cannot be embedded (copy of core.img stored early on in a gap at start of disk) so needs to use an UNRELIABLE method ( Sigh!) this is the same state as before this change BTW.

For many other users, they will have grub installed as the initial bootloader. In this case you can just do:

```
# grub-install  /dev/sda
```

This is a more common place for grub (and works better)

So I booted this, selected kubuntu-SDA7 as the boot option, it booted fine. I made the above DEBUGGING change (renaming one to **NOT-vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic**) and it sill booted fine ...so it's no longer using /oldboot.